# clasification of teaching licensures and certifications particularly for teacher-students

Tags: teacher-training, teaching, certification

There is a lot of certification and licensure tests for teaching (math and etc) particularly for teachers and teacher-students (PACT, Praxis & PPAT, edTPA, RESA, ... in US and TAT in India and etc). These tests are usually named as TPA -Teaching Performance Assessment. Where can I see a full list of these tests and where can I see these tests classified by those goals, methods or contents? Where can I see a list of especial tests for teacher-students?

Comment: There are some Praxis ones (by U.S. state) listed [**here**](https://www.ets.org/praxis/states)...

Comment: I doubt there is a full list of them anywhere.  At least in the US, each state has its own requirements and when you start getting into other countries i'm sure it gets even more complicated.  The Praxis I and II are the most popular tests in the US, follow @BenjaminDickman link to see that list.